# swiftui vstack item filling space

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a view that has two items. One of them is aligned to the bottom and the other should fill out the available space BUT with having space at top that is the same height as my bottom item. I tried doing it by adding a Spacer top and setting the middle view `maxHeight` to `infinity`. This looks close to what I want but not quite right. The `Spacer` needs to match the height of the bottom view. In `UIKit` this was achieved by having the top empty view height be constrained as equal to the bottom view.

```
VStack {
   Spacer()

   Item1().frame(maxHeight: .infinity)

   Item2()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place `Item2` at the top and hide it by giving it opacity of 0:

```
VStack {
   Item2()
      .opacity(0)
   Item1()
      .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
   Item2()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
VStack {
   Spacer().frame(height: 100)

   Item1().frame(maxHeight: .infinity)

   Item2().frame(height: 100)
}
```

This will give the same height to your spacer as well as your Item2